# Are there any Koroks in the depths?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Are there any Koroks or Koroks Seeds to find in the underground depths? I've found them in the Sky and on the Surface, but I haven't spotted any in the Depths yet.

Comment: Don't give the devs any ideas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Nintendo Life](https://www.nintendolife.com/guides/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom-all-korok-seed-locations#are-there-any-koroks-hiding-in-the-depths):

> As far as we've been able to tell, Koroks are only found in the Sky and Surface areas of Hyrule — there are no Koroks to find in the Depths

I also found some interactive maps that show no Korok seeds in the depths, such as [this map](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/tears-of-the-kingdom-interactive-map/?z=1&x=250&y=0&l=Depths).

Comment: There *are* a few Koroks in the depths below the lost woods, actually, but they don't award Korok seeds, and they're not hiding.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I don't have the game, but I assume these are like... NPC type Koroks then?

Comment: Correct! They (rot13 minor spoilers) yrnq lbh gbjneqf gur ragenapr gb gur ybfg jbbqf, fvapr gur "abezny" jnl vf oybpxrq.